# How to fetch only the latest email using Gmail API in Python

Tags: python

How would I ago about coding a Python script to work whenever there is a new email in my inbox. Is there any special tools in the Gmail Python SDK that would make this easy to do instead of using MAPI and going the long rout of keep checking daily for new inbox updates?

Comment: Have you looked into push notifications? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Comment: Yes, but i really don’t know how to implement it in Python up to the point of extracting the email. I am a bit new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
def get_email():
    #credentials
    username ="youremail@gmail.com"
    #generated app password
    app_password= "emailPasswd"
    # https://www.systoolsgroup.com/imap/
    gmail_host= 'imap.gmail.com'
    #set connection
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(gmail_host)
    #login
    mail.login(username, app_password)
    #select inbox
    mail.select("INBOX")
    time.sleep(1)
    #select specific mails
    _, selected_mails = mail.search(None,"UNSEEN", '(FROM "specificUser@gmail.com")') # get emails only from specific sender
    #total number of mails from specific user
    for num in selected_mails[0].split():
        your_function() # call your function here so for every new mail this will run
        _, data = mail.fetch(num , '(RFC822)')
        _, bytes_data = data[0]
        #access data
        subject_of_mail = email_message["subject"] 
            for part in email_message.walk():
                if part.get_content_type()=="text/plain" or part.get_content_type()=="text/html":
                    message = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        else:
            pass

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(get_email)

#other schedule options
"""
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(get_email)
schedule.every().hour.do(get_email)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(get_email)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(get_email)
schedule.every().monday.do(get_email)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(get_email)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(get_email)
"""
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```